Problem with apache camel in quarkus when saving exchange variables
Good afternoon, I am currently working with Apache Camel in Quarkus, basically my microservice is called identifyOrigin and it calls another microservice called getActivateSessionByIp, I want to apply cache to this call and I am using the following logic for the same:
Class ResRoute
@ApplicationScoped
public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "client.url.userProfile")
    String urlUserProfile;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "client.utl.getActiveSessionByIp")
    String urlGetActivateSessionByIp;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
    String descriptionService;

    private ConfigureSsl configureSsl;

    private static final String SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION = "Salida Microservicio IdentifyOrigin ${body}";
    private static final String MSG_EXCEPTION = "Descripcion de la Exception: ${exception.message}";

    private static final String DATE_LOG = "[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] ";

    public RestRoute() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
        configureSsl= new ConfigureSsl();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        BeanDate beanDate= new BeanDate();
        getContext().getRegistry().bind("BeanDate", beanDate);

        restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures","FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .clientRequestValidation(true)
                .apiProperty("api.title","IdentifyOrigin")
                .apiProperty("api.description",descriptionService)
                .apiProperty("api-version","1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors","true");
        rest("/")
                .produces("application/json")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .post("/identifyOrigin/v1/info")
                .type(Request.class)
                .outType(ResponseSuccess.class)
                .param().name("Response").type(RestParamType.body).description("Parametros de Salidas")
                .endParam().to("direct:pipeline");

                from("direct:pipeline")
                        .doTry()
                            .log("["+"${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}"+"] "+ "Valor Header x-correlator: ${header.x-correlator}")
                            .to("bean-validator:validateRequest")
                            .log("["+"${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}"+"] "+ "Datos de Entrada del MS: ${body}")
                             /*Processor classes to create the Microservice Request to call GetActiveSession and Ip */
                            .process(new GetActivateSessionByIpReqProcessor())
                            .log("\n[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] "+"Entrada Microservicio GetActivateSessionByIp: ${exchangeProperty[getActivateSessionByIpRequest]}")
                             /* Configure the parameters for the cache*/
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_GET))
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("ipAddress")
                            .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "GetActiveSessionByIpCache")
                            .log("Hay Resultado en Cache de la consulta asociado a la IP Consultada: ${exchangeProperty[ipAddress]} ${header.CamelCaffeineActionHasResult}")
                            .log("CamelCaffeineActionSucceeded: ${header.CamelCaffeineActionSucceeded}")
                            .choice()
                                /* It is queried if there is a result in the cache for the sent id*/
                                .when(header(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_HAS_RESULT).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE))
                                    .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), urlGetActivateSessionByIp))
                                    /* A process class is used to validate the response and take different actions depending on the type of response*/
                                    .process(new GetActivateSessionByIpResProcessor())
                                    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_PUT))
                                    .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("ipAddress")
                                    .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "GetActiveSessionByIpCache")
                                .otherwise()
                                        .log("Cache is working")
                                         .process(new GetActivateSessionByIpResProcessor())
                                .endChoice()
                            .end()
                            /* It is required to validate if the http response type is 200, 400, 404, so a log will be used to see it.*/
                             .log("Resultado header: ${exchangeProperty[httpResponseCode]}")
                        .endDoTry()
    }
}

The problem happens is that at first I captured the http response value of the microservice getActivateSessionByIp and at first if it was 200, I got the required fields, otherwise I threw an exception and controlled response, here what I would like is how can I use the cache For these cases, it would be necessary to reformulate my code, since I am noticing that when I made my first query everything was fine, but when it goes to the cache the service does not recognize the http code variable and throws a null pointer exception
This is how my first query happens, you can see that I can see the response code in the httpResponseCode variable:
First query (not cached):

Second Query (It is cached):

I attach my processor classes so they know what it contains:
GetActivateSessionByIpReqProcessor
@ApplicationScoped
public class GetActivateSessionByIpReqProcessor implements Processor {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final IGetActivateSessionByIpMappingReq getActivateSessionByIpMappingReq;

    public GetActivateSessionByIpReqProcessor() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        getActivateSessionByIpMappingReq=new GetActivateSessionByIpMappingReqImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Request request=exchange.getIn().getBody(Request.class);
        String correlatorId = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-correlator")).map(Object::toString).orElse("c8ff2443-1b49-4f5f-8412-3fecbb10b836");
        String ipAddress=request.getIpAddress();
        String port= String.valueOf(request.getPort());
        RequestGetActivateSessionByIp requestGetActivateSessionByIp=getActivateSessionByIpMappingReq.toRequest(ipAddress,port);
        String jsonGetActivateSessionByIpMappingReq = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestGetActivateSessionByIp);
        exchange.setProperty("getActivateSessionByIpRq", requestGetActivateSessionByIp);
        exchange.setProperty("getActivateSessionByIpRequest", jsonGetActivateSessionByIpMappingReq);
        exchange.setProperty("correlatorId", correlatorId);
        exchange.setProperty("ipAddress", ipAddress);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, "/api/v1/getActivateSessionByIp");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("x-transaction-id", correlatorId);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("x-user", "UsuarioKernel");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("x-token", "bc4a129867486c6ee7436fa6111c2e");
        exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonGetActivateSessionByIpMappingReq);

    }
}

GetActivateSessionByIpResProcessor
@ApplicationScoped
public class GetActivateSessionByIpResProcessor implements Processor {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public GetActivateSessionByIpResProcessor() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        String bodyResponse=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String httpResponseCode=exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelHttpResponseCode", String.class);
        ResponseGetActivateSessionByIp responseGetActivateSessionByIp= objectMapper.readValue(bodyResponse,ResponseGetActivateSessionByIp.class);
        String jsonGetActivateSessionByIpRs = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseGetActivateSessionByIp);
        String phoneNumberByIp=responseGetActivateSessionByIp.getId();
        exchange.setProperty("phoneNumberByIp", phoneNumberByIp);
        exchange.setProperty("httpResponseCode", httpResponseCode);

    }
}

What could be happening?

You set exchange property httpResponseCode from the value of header CamelHttpResponseCode. CamelHttpResponseCode header is something you have to set manually (otherwise looking it up will return null). So maybe you're not doing that in the scenario where you retrieve data from your cache.

@JamesNetherton According to what you say, where should the line go, within otherwhise where does it say that the cache is working?

Does this line make a http request: .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), urlGetActivateSessionByIp))?
